# are non-android, phonemodel-specific questions appropriate here?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions, question-appropriateness

For example, which (if any) of these questions are appropriate? These questions are specific to android phones, but not android-related.

- Questions about Droid spec
- Questions about connecting Samsung Kies with Galaxy S
- Questions about HTC Desire battery life
- Questions about comparing two android phones

etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would think it's perfectly appropriate. Android is defined by the range of available options there is; and not as drones of unified, all-encompassing, all-similar of device. There is a range of Androids with touchscreen and slide-out keyboards; or touchpad and directional pad; and often what's the best answer for one device configuration is totally inappropriate for another.

An equivalent question would be: "are language-specific programming questions appropriate in StackOverflow?"

Comment: I concur. The site is for Android phones as well as the Android OS and applications which run thereon.

Comment: Addendum: Recommendations ("Which phone should I buy?") are off-topic.